# REPLACE in mysql can't work with free space. how to rename free space?

Tags: mysql

text to replace

> Probijalniki/Ĺ karje za pločevino

i want to use REPLACE in mysql

```
UPDATE pages SET title = REPLACE(title, 'Ĺ ', 'Š');
```

but i get Affected rows: 0

Why i can not replace 'Ĺ ' with 'Š'. I can replace 'Ĺ' but not with space 'Ĺ '

Comment: I suggest you the following: set every charset to UTF-8, try first select replace(...) from pages, before running the update, try to prepend 'n' to the string like this: n'Ĺ '. See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work. But there is one good reason why it wouldn't.

You don't have any 'Ĺ ' in your db. You might have something that LOOKS like a space but isn't.

Create test data and manually type in 'Ĺ ' into the table and run your query. It worked for me.